# How to increase node size?

Tags: flowchart, mermaid

I want to know if there is a way to set a specific size in a node shape using mermaid flowchart

I managed to change node color using:

```
style D fill:#fc6b03
```

and tried add size this way but did not work:

```
style D fill:#fc6b03 size:100
```

Comment: It is not programming specific question and as result off-topic on SO (the fact on can use a tool in programming context - like Lnux/Windows - is not enough to be considered on-topic... ) Possibly on-topic on SuperUser.

Comment: I did this, and my question was migrated here again